# Azure AD Connect failing to configure AAD Sync

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

While following the Azure AD Connect v1.1.189.0 installation wizard ([release history](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-version-history/)), at "Configure" step, I receive the following message:

> **Create Federated AAD Trust**
>
> An error occurred while executing the 'Convert-MsolDomainToFederated' command. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

When, I check the domain status by `Get-MsolDomain` I get

> Authentication: Federated

When I retry, I get another error.

> **Configure AAD Sync**
>
> Element 'ma-run-data' was not found. Line 1, position 2.

I returned the domain's Authentication to Managed using `Set-MsolDomainAuthentication -DomainName contoso.com -Authentication Managed`, uninstalled the Azure AD Connect and retried several times.

- ADFS and ADFS-WAP are already setup and working.
- Azure AD Connect server edition is 2012 R2 fully updated.
- [Azure AD Connect perquisites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-prerequisites/) are met.
- No firewall ports/protocols are blocked or inspected.
- Tried with both .NET Framework 4.5.2 and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: [trace-20160701-121956.log](http://pastebin.com/Sir2EJ2r)